# Как заставить ComboBox открывать список вверх, а не вниз?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как заставить ComboBox открывать список вверх, а не вниз? Я понимаю, что надо переопределить шаблон `ControlTemplate`, хотелось бы увидеть пример кода.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825845/wpf-combobox-dropdown-placement) что нашел

Comment: А как с помощью `XAML` переопределить шаблон?

Comment: при переопределении шаблона увидите popup. Там и задайте его расположениею